# Ubuntu hangs at purple screen - how do I fix this?

Tags: boot, command-line, grub2, nvidia

When I try to boot Ubuntu (17.04), it just hangs at the purple screen. The only way to get out is to force my computer to shut down by holding the power button.

Other people have reported this problem in the past, but none of the solutions work for me. I take it they're either outdated, or there's something wrong with my installation preventing me from using them.

- Previous answers will say to press CTRL+ALT+F1 to access a command line. This doesn't work for me. I am able to access a command line by pressing "c" on the grub menu, but it's a special "grub" command line and doesn't contain the usual sudo commands.
- When I try recover mode, I don't have the "mount the disk as read/write" option. It just takes me to a command line which is different from the grub one, but *still* doesn't contain the usual sudo commands.

I don't know exactly what's causing the problem, but I recently installed the NVIDIA proprietary driver, and I hear drivers tend to cause problems like that. Ubuntu was able to boot fine before then.

In case it's important, I'm dual-booting with Windows 10, though I doubt that would make a difference.

EDIT: As requested, here are my specs according to the dxdiag feature in Windows. I'm still new to Linux so I don't know what information is relevant to it and what isn't.

- System Manufacturer: Dell Inc.
- System Model: Inspiron 17 7000 Series 7746
- BIOS: A04
- Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5500U CPU @ 2.40GHz (4 CPUs), ~2.4GHz
- Memory: 16384MB RAM

Display:

- Card name: Intel(R) HD Graphics 5500
- Manufacturer: Intel Corporation
- Chip type: Intel(R) HD Graphics Family
- DAC type: Internal
- Device Type: Full Device
- Device Key: Enum\PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1616&SUBSYS_06921028&REV_09
- Device Status: 0180200A [DN_DRIVER_LOADED|DN_STARTED|DN_DISABLEABLE|DN_NT_ENUMERATOR|DN_NT_DRIVER]
- Device Problem Code: No Problem
- Driver Problem Code: Unknown
- Display Memory: 8275 MB
- Dedicated Memory: 128 MB
- Shared Memory: 8147 MB

Render:

- Card name: NVIDIA GeForce 845M
- Manufacturer: NVIDIA
- Chip type: GeForce 845M
- DAC type: Integrated RAMDAC
- Device Type: Render-Only Device
- Device Key: Enum\PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_1344&SUBSYS_06921028&REV_A2
- Device Status: 0180200A [DN_DRIVER_LOADED|DN_STARTED|DN_DISABLEABLE|DN_NT_ENUMERATOR|DN_NT_DRIVER]
- Device Problem Code: No Problem
- Driver Problem Code: Unknown
- Display Memory: 10167 MB
- Dedicated Memory: 2019 MB
- Shared Memory: 8147 MB

I installed the proprietary driver through the option in the Unity GUI. I don't remember the exact steps, but it *wasn't* through the terminal. I waited until it finished downloading and shut down Ubuntu properly.

Comment: *drivers tend to cause problems like that* No, not really. Wrong drivers and/or incorrectly installed drivers cause problems like that. Please [edit] and post hardware specs, namely the graphics model, which driver version and *how* did you install it.

Comment: @MichaelBay OP can't get in so how OP supposed to post additional information?

Comment: When in recovery mode commandline run `mount -o rw,remount /`, to mount the filesystem

Comment: @George Pardon me? I'm sure they can edit the post the same way they posted it in the first place. The information I requested doesn't need access, I mean, owners should know what hardware they have, namely Nvidia cards, and likely they should remember which driver and how it was installed... All of it we need to know in order to help. How the driver was installed determines how it needs to be uninstalled and to find out the proper driver one has to know the card's model.

Comment: @MichaelBay I don't know my hardware that well (at least until I get into trouble, :)), but OP should know how those drivers were installed. OP can do a `mount -o rw,remount /` to uninstall

Comment: @George I'm sure you would find out which Nvidia graphics you have before installing proprietary drivers or, at least, you would just pick up the recommendation in Additional Drivers. Either way you should be fine :)