# 16.04 Freezes on Purple Screen after booting Windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, lenovo

Long story short: *I launched Windows 10 on my dual boot machine yesterday, it acted buggy for a while and crashed a couple times, and now Ubuntu doesn't boot any more.*

I booted up my Windows install (I dual boot...) yesterday and it ran some updates and acted pretty buggy. I ended up having to force a shut down (hold down the power button) and after that Windows was showing some weird behavior. It also did several rounds of updates. In the end, it started acting normal but was running a little slow/choppy. Oh, one other thing. The Lenovo Solution Center crashed when it was running a hardware scan.

Later yesterday I tried to boot up my Ubuntu install. Grub let me choose Ubuntu and immediately froze on the Purple screen right after. If I go into Advanced Options for Ubuntu and choose the top choice my system loads as expected.

I don't think that I've made any weird modifications to grub though I did have to tinker with some BIOS stuff to get Ubuntu to play nicely with Windows, but this was over a year ago and I've had no problems.

One other thing: a pop up while I was running Windows told me that (Lenovo, I think?) wanted to update my Bios (I run Lenovo, so this is plausible) but I declined.

I'll update if I can think of anything else.

I run a

- Lenovo T450s w/
- quad core 2.60GHz Intel i7-5600u, and
- Intel Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
- 20G memory

Comment: This sounds very much like a Windows problem. Were you by any chance trying to install the Windows 10 Creators update (1709)?

Comment: It almost definitely is a windows problem. I'm not familiar with that update but if it's automatically installed by windows then maybe. I hadn't updated in about six months

Comment: Sorry, just looked it up. Yes, that is the update that was installed (99% certain)

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/654386/windows-10-upgrade-led-to-grub-rescue also https://askubuntu.com/questions/940432/ubuntu-hangs-at-purple-screen-how-do-i-fix-this

Comment: The creators update attempts to install automatically, but often fails, requiring an alternate approach. From an Ubuntu perspective, you might just [reinstall grub.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/831216/reinstalling-grub2-efi-partition) This assumes that your [drive is ok.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528072/how-can-i-check-the-smart-status-of-a-ssd-or-hdd-on-current-versions-of-ubuntu-1)